# Flash SWF inside CefSharp browser doesn't appear to register double click events

Tags: flash, cefsharp, double-click, ppapi

There is a lot of things to be considered here so I was just generally wondering if anyone has gotten a SWF flash file to fully work inside a CefSharp browser in WPF more specifically the double-click events for the flash SWF.

Right now everything appears to work for me except the double-click events. These appear to work fine in Chrome but not in CefSharp. I have tried hooking up to a few different versions of `pepflash.dll` but no dice.

Versions tried:

- `pepflashplayer32_30_0_0_113.dll`
- `pepflashplayer32_29_0_0_171.dll`

Comment: Substituting **MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK** with a script based on **MouseEvent.CLICK** is not an option?

Comment: That is not an option right now cause at the moment that would take many days of work for the team. We have many scripts that we would have to change. 

What is strange is how Chromium in the chrome browser has no issue doing it but CefSharp doesnt like it.

Comment: I don't think it's **THAT** much of work, actually. Detection script aside (it should work on the **stage** level), all you will need to do is to replace **MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK** with a custom event name everywhere you use it.

Comment: Have you checked this upstream using a version of `CEF`? Download a sample application and test it: http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, I guess. I didn't check it so please forgive me for any typos. But in theory that should do the trick. As I said above the only other thing to do is to replace **MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK** with the **DoubleClick.DOUBLE_CLICK** everywhere you listen to it and it will magically work. Probably.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class DoubleClick
    {
        // Don't occasionally set it to actual MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK
        // because you'll get twice as many events on the platforms
        // where original MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK actually works.
        static public const DOUBLE_CLICK:String = "custom.double";

        // How far the Mouse can click for the second time so that
        // it will still count as double click (in pixels).
        static public const distanceTreshold:int = 5;

        // How fast the second click has to happen for these two clicks
        // to still be considered a double click (in milliseconds).
        static public const timeoutTreshold:int = 500;

        static private var stage:Stage;

        // Call it to initialize the custom double click engine.
        static public function attachTo(target:Stage):void
        {
            stage = target;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

            Click.stage = stage;
        }

        static private var lastClick:Click;

        static private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Sanity check. If the event target is not attached to
            // the display list then it is pointless to proceed.
            if (!e.target.stage)
            {
                if (lastClick)
                {
                    lastClick.destroy();
                    lastClick = null;
                }

                return;
            }

            var aClick:Click = new Click(e.target as DisplayObject);

            if (!lastClick)
            {
                // If there was no previous clicks then just remember this one.
                lastClick = aClick;
            }
            else if (checkDouble(aClick))
            {
                // Yay! Double click seems to happen!
                dispatchDouble(aClick, e);
            }
            else
            {
                // If these two clicks don't qualify as double, just
                // forget the previous one and remember the new one.
                lastClick.destroy();
                lastClick = aClick;
            }
        }

        // Return true if the second click was fast enough and close enough.
        static private function checkDouble(click:Click):Boolean
        {
            if (Math.abs(click.x - lastClick.x) > distanceTreshold) return false;
            if (Math.abs(click.y - lastClick.y) > distanceTreshold) return false;

            if (click.time - lastClick.time > timeoutTreshold) return false;

            return true;
        }

        static private function dispatchDouble(click:Click, e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Get the bottommost display object as a
            // starting point for the double click event,
            // because between the first and second clicks
            // some other objects could appear or disappear
            // under the mouse, so the second click might not
            // actually be the second for the designated target.
            var aTarget:DisplayObject = lastClick.deepestCommon(click);

            // Compose the event.
            var anEvent:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent
            (
                DOUBLE_CLICK, // Event.type
                true,         // Event.bubbles
                false,        // Event.cancelable

                e.localX,     // Copies of original event properties.
                e.localY,
                e.relatedObject,
                e.ctrlKey,
                e.altKey,
                e.shiftKey,
                e.buttonDown,
                e.delta,
                e.commandKey,
                e.controlKey,

                2            // MouseEvent.clickCount
            );

            // Clean up things.
            lastClick.destroy();
            lastClick = null;

            click.destroy();

            // Emulate the double click event.
            aTarget.dispatchEvent(anEvent);
        }
    }
}

import flash.utils.getTimer;

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

// This is basically a data structure to keep
// basic information about a single click.
internal class Click
{
    static public var stage:Stage;

    public var x:int;
    public var y:int;

    public var time:int;
    public var path:Array;

    public function Click(target:DisplayObject)
    {
        x = stage.mouseX;
        y = stage.mouseY;

        time = getTimer();
        path = [target];

        // Unwind the full path from stage to the target.
        var aParent:DisplayObjectContainer = target.parent;

        while (aParent)
        {
            path.unshift(aParent);
            aParent = aParent.parent;
        }

        // At this point the path should contain something like
        // [stage, .. , .. , .. , target.parent, target]
    }

    // Release the path Array.
    public function destroy():void
    {
        if (path)
        {
            path.length = 0;
            path = null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the deepest DisplayObject that
    // both click passed through along their ways.
    public function deepestCommon(click:Click):DisplayObject
    {
        // At very least they have stage as the common point.
        var result:DisplayObject = path[0];

        for (var i:int = 1; i < Math.min(path.length, click.path.length); i++)
        {
            if (path[i] != click.path[i]) break;

            result = path[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will keep this in mind in case we decide to have someone do that for us. Right now the problem with doing this is that we have many .fla files and many scripts. It would not just be a simple one .fla that we needed to fix but many, large .fla that would need to convert the double click functionality to the single click functionality. But I will keep this in mind just in case we have no other choice.